# AWS Documentation on Java Assuming STS Client not working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk, aws-sts

As a prereq see [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AuthUsingTempSessionTokenJava.html) page.

So I can created a small app that is literally a copy-paste of the code they provide. It does run for the given user, I have changed the global variables to the proper values, and I can assume the STS Role that I want via the AWS CLI. However this code will still not assume the proper role.

I export the code as an executable jar, put it up onto my EC2 instance (basic AWS linux instance), and run it. I do have it output the keys from the STS Credentials which are proper and correct, but as soon as it gets down to the S3 client I get access denied (403).

My roles are as follows:

- The EC2 has no role, but in the credentials file has a user access information (let's call him MyUser)
- MyUser has the ability to assume the STS role and IAM functionality (IAM functionality is not necessary, it's just for testing purposes)
- The STS role is assumable only by MyUser, and allows full access to S3 within the account

AWS Documentation is hit or miss sometimes, but I can't find anyone else experiencing issues with this code. Like I said if I do the same process of assuming the STS role via CLI, I can do that and it works properly which makes this much more confusing.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

Comment: Are your running this code and the CLI from the same machine using the same credentials?

Comment: Yes. The EC2 has no permissions. It has the credentials in it of MyUser, therefore it acts as the user. I run the cli on this instance. I call the assume role CLI command and adjust the environment variables properly. When I try S3 commands they work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page you [linked](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AuthUsingTempSessionTokenJava.html) has wrong code according to their documentation. The AssumeRole method has different example code is incorrect. There is other documentation that solves the issue see this [page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/securitytoken/AWSSecurityTokenService.html#assumeRole-com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AssumeRoleRequest-). The API documentation example has

```
AssumeRoleResult response = client.assumeRole(request);
```

Where the AssumeRole function returns a AssumeRoleResult object, which has different credentials than the credentials that return from the GetSessionTokenRequest class. The Credentials returned are different lengths/sizes and for some reason invalid.

THE FIX:

This code shown on their [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AuthUsingTempSessionTokenJava.html) is invalid.

```
stsClient.assumeRole(roleRequest);
GetSessionTokenRequest getSessionTokenRequest = new GetSessionTokenRequest();
getSessionTokenRequest.setDurationSeconds(900);
GetSessionTokenResult sessionTokenResult = stsClient.getSessionToken(getSessionTokenRequest);
Credentials sessionCredentials = sessionTokenResult.getCredentials();
```

The code above should be replaced with the following found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/securitytoken/AWSSecurityTokenService.html#assumeRole-com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AssumeRoleRequest-).

```
AssumeRoleResult response = stsClient.assumeRole(roleRequest);
Credentials sessionCredentials = response.getCredentials();
```